# Magento 2 undefind function Magento\Framework\Stdlib\iconv_strlen() in vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/StringUtils.php?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, server-setup, zend-framework, frontend-error

I am getting the below error when I upload my project to live server.Everything is working perfect in my local system.But The below error only getting on server

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Stdlib\iconv_strlen() in **/home/mydomain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/StringUtils.php** on line **151**

Can you help me on this.What to do.

Comment: iconv is actually a part of PHP already, have you disabled it?  http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php

Comment: Go to php.ini and check for extension=iconv.so in your live server.

Comment: it is already enabled.Please check this url : http://sunrisefabricators.co.in/phpinfo.php

Comment: It may be not available, please read the source carefully and check https://www.hackersgarage.com/iconv-php-extension-installation-without-recompiling-php.html

Comment: ok, I will go through it.